# Add html content to div id

Tags: html, jquery

Here is my html:

```
<div id="activities-area" class="col col-12 bg-light full-height">
    <div class="activity-row">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block activity-button">Some sort of activity</button>
    </div>
<div class="activity-row">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block activity-button">Some sort of activity</button>
</div>
```

All I am trying to do is inject further instances of the class `activity-row` into the `<div id="activity-area">`.

So, when another `<button>` is clicked I want to grab the html associated with that `<button>`. Lets say:

```
'<div class="activity-row"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block activity-button">Some sort of activity</button></div>'
```

and all I want to do is append it to the content already in the `#activity-area` div.

Have tried things like:

```
$("#activity-area").append("<markup here>")
```

to no avail. Would appreciate any assistance, please, on how to add html to that div id. Thank you.

Comment: Typo on your class... `$("#activity-area")` should be `$("#activities-area")`

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo on your Jquery for your `id` selector:

> Jquery code: `$("#activity-area")`

The actual `id` is `activities-area` not `activity-area` so it should be `$("#activities-area")` instead.

Comment: AAAAAAAArrrrgghhhh! Thank you!